# Oracle sqlplus logging stops

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, logfiles

This is strange...

I'm running a script in sqlplus. It seeems to have completed it's function, however when I review the .log it seems to have stopped logging...has anyone else had this experience?

I think I may have opened the logfile at some stage while the script was running to check process, perhaps that's no-no?

The redacted details are:

```
set serveroutput on;
set feedback off;
set echo on;
spool 4logfilethatstops.log

BEGIN

/*-----------------------------------------*/
/* Establishing AUID on dmt_identifier table*/
update DMT_CUSTOMER_ID
set auid=CUSTOMER_ID
where CUSTOMER_ID_ZONE_OFFICE = '&&var_DM_ID_ZONE_OFFICEority'
and batch_id = '&&var_batchid';

/*-----------------------------------------*/
/*Copying DM_ID to all tables*/

update dmt_ a 
set DM_ID= (select CUSTOMER_ID from DMT_CUSTOMER_ID b 
            where b.PRI_CLT_RECORD_ID=a.PRI_CLT_RECORD_ID 
            and b.batch_id = '&&var_batchid'
            and b.CUSTOMER_ID_ZONE_OFFICE = '&&var_DM_ID_ZONE_OFFICEority'
            and b.CUSTOMER_ID_major_flag = 'Y'
            and b.CUSTOMER_ID_type_code = '004')
where a.batch_id = '&&var_batchid';
```

[10 more similar statements]

```
/*-----------------------------------------*/
/*Exclude records with no DM_IDs*/

update dmt_address c
            set c.batch_id = c.batch_id||'-EXCLUDE'
            where c.batch_id = '&&var_batchid'
            and c.pri_clt_record_id in 
            (SELECT pri_clt_record_id FROM dmt_ 
             where DM_ID is NULL );
```

[10 more similar statements]

```
/*-----------------------------------------*/
/*Exclude merged records from dmt_ tables*/

update dmt_ c
            set batch_id = batch_id||'-EXCLUDE'
            where batch_id not like '%EXCLUDE%'
            and c.pri_clt_record_id in
            (select b.pri_clt_record_id from dmt_ a , dmt_ b
            where a.container_sequence_number = b.container_sequence_number
            and b.rpl_pri_clt_record_id = a.pri_clt_record_id 
            and a.rpl_pri_clt_record_id is null);
```

[1 more similar statement]

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------*/
/*Exclude dmt_insurance records from dmt_ that are not MRA*/

update dmt_insurance
set batch_id = batch_id||'-EXCLUDE'
where batch_id not like '%EXCLUDE%'
and client_insurance_record_id not like 'MRA-%';

/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
/*Populate dmt_demog with dmt_profile data*/

update dmt_staticdemographics a 
set MSTATUS=(select CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_CODE 
            from dmt_profile 
            where CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_CODE = 02
            and batch_id = '&&var_batchid'
            and PRI_CLT_RECORD_ID=a.PRI_CLT_RECORD_ID);
```

[4 more similar statements]

```
 /*--------------------*/
/*Populate DM_* tables*/
/*----------------*/
/*inserting person*/

insert into dm_person 
            (CUSTOMER_ID, DOB,DOB_EST,SEX,
            CREATED_DATE,LAST_UPDATE_DATE, batch_id)
select DM_ID, DATE_OF_BIRTH,DATE_OF_BIRTH_ESTIMATION_FLAG,
            SEX_CODE,MSTATUS,INDIGENOUS,RELIGION,LANGUAGE
            from dmt_staticdemographics
            where DM_ID is not null
            and  batch_id = '&&var_batchid';
```

[3 more similar statements]

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
-- inserting external identifiers
insert into DM_IDENTIFIER
  (CUSTOMER_ID,IDENTIFIER_START_DATE,IDENTIFIER_END_DATE,IDENTIFIER_TYPE,ID_VALUE,CREATED_DATE,LAST_UPDATE_DATE, BATCH_ID, ZONE_OFFICEority)
select DM_ID,effective_start_date,effective_end_date, ext_clt_id_type_code, EXT_CLT_ID,SOURCE_CREATE_DATETIME, SOURCE_MODIFIED_DATETIME, 
            BATCH_ID, ext_clt_id_ZONE_OFFICE
from dmt_extidentifier
            where DM_ID is not null
            and batch_id = '&&var_batchid';
```

[4 more similar statements]

```
            COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: what do you mean, stopped logging?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything *to* log. You haven't shown any `dbms_output` statements, and you've set `feedback off` so you won't get a PL/SQL block completion message. You might see prompts for the substitution variables and their replacements I guess.

Comment: By default, sql*plus will give a short feedback when an sql statement was issued. For example, if a table was created, sql*plus will tell the user: Table created. Or, if a procedure has ended, sql*plus lets one know: PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. 2 things are missing here I think, feedback should be on and spool off should be there as mentioned in above comments.

Comment: Thanks all...I'll: edit by deleting 'set feedback off;' at the beginning, setting a 'dbms_output' at the beginning, and 'spool off' at the end. I'll give it a burl on Monday.

Comment: @be here now By "stopped logging' I mean output a logging file as expectsd, with only part of the expected contents. The logging seems to have stopped halfway.